# Typescript - 'No overload matches this call' when using fetched data and material-ui

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom, material-ui, object-literal

I practiced creating a dropdown menu with

1. hardcoded array before trying to create a
2. dropdown menu with an array retrieved with useSWR.

I used this for the first practice: https://codesandbox.io/s/76k0ft?file=/demo.tsx:1819-2045

Instead of using the hardcoded `names` variable,I saved a fetched array as shown:

```
const { data, error } = useSWR(
    "https://api.github.com/repos/vercel/swr",
    fetcher
);
if (error) return <h1>"An error has occurred."</h1>;
if (!data) return <h1>"Loading..."</h1>;
const arr = data.topics;
```

I rendered it as shown:

```
{arr.map((tag,id)=> (
     <MenuItem
          key={id}
          value={tag}
     >
        {tag}
     </MenuItem>
))}
```

To which I was given red underlines for the parameter that says the following when cursor is placed over the `tag` and `id` parameters.

> Parameter 'tag' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

I clicked on the suggested Quick fixes and now the MenuItem and its props are underlined.

After Quick fixes it looks like this

```
{arr.map((tag: {} | null | undefined,id: React.Key | null | undefined)=> (
     <MenuItem
          key={id}
          value={tag}
     >
         {tag}
     </MenuItem>
))}
```

The message I get from hovering over the red underlines is

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 3, '(props: { href:
> string; } & { autoFocus?: boolean | undefined; classes?:
> Partial | undefined; dense?: boolean | undefined;
> disabled?: boolean | undefined; disableGutters?: boolean | undefined;
> divider?: boolean | undefined; selected?: boolean | undefined; sx?:
> SxProps<...> | undefined; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>):
> Element', gave the following error.
> Type '{ children: {} | null | undefined; key: Key | null | undefined; value: {} | null | undefined; }' is not assignable to type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & { href: string; } & { autoFocus?: boolean |
> undefined; classes?: Partial | undefined; dense?:
> boolean | undefined; ... 4 more ...; sx?: SxProps<...> | undefined; }
> & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>'.
> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { href: string; } & { autoFocus?: boolean | undefined; classes?:
> Partial | undefined; dense?: boolean | undefined; ...
> 4 more ...; sx?: SxProps<...> | undefined; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps
> & Omit<...>'.   Overload 2 of 3, '(props: { component:
> ElementType; } & { autoFocus?: boolean | undefined; classes?:
> Partial | undefined; dense?: boolean | undefined; ...
> 4 more ...; sx?: SxProps<...> | undefined; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps
> & Omit<...>): Element', gave the following error.
> Property 'component' is missing in type '{ children: {} | null | undefined; key: Key | null | undefined; value: {} | null | undefined;
> }' but required in type '{ component: ElementType; }'.   Overload
> 3 of 3, '(props:
> DefaultComponentProps<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<MenuItemTypeMap<{},
> "li">>>): Element', gave the following error.
> Type '{} | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'.ts(2769) OverridableComponent.d.ts(17,
> 7): 'component' is declared here. index.d.ts(2246, 9): The expected
> type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & { autoFocus?: boolean | undefined; classes?:
> Partial | undefined; dense?: boolean | undefined; ...
> 4 more ...; sx?: SxProps<...> | undefined; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps
> & Omit<...>'

**What is the difference between mapping through a hardcoded array and an array fetched using useSRW?** There were no red underline in the first example.

The code works, but I am trying to understand how Typescript works. I also get this warning message in the console:

> react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array listed in the sandbox is an array of `string`. Therefore mapping the individual element should give a string. Hope this helps.

```
{arr.map((tag:string,id:number)=> (
     <MenuItem
          key={id}
          value={tag}
     >
        {tag}
     </MenuItem>
))}
```